# How to fix JAVA_HOME is invalid for cordova

Tags: java, cordova, sdk

I have tried reinstalling the JDK a few times
 reset the JAVA_HOME
 I know that the JAVA_HOME needs to be set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102
I know PATH has to be set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin
I am confused as to why you have to set user variables and system variables
I set both the JAVA_HOME and the PATH in both User vairables and System variables
I have added "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools" and "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools" System "Variables/Path"

Here is an Image of most of the settings, I have tried a few things and cant seem to find the problem any help please

[image: Settings and Files]

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question, but have you tried restarting your command prompt since changing the JAVA_HOME path? Environment variables are only loaded upon launching the command prompt, so to get the effects of changes you need to restart it.

Comment: agree with @Jokab  need to restart cmd after set every environment variable for get effect..

Comment: maybe also obvious, but... are you sure you have `jdk1.8.0_102`??

Comment: Yeah done all this i understand that the Session needs to be restarted for the parameters to be updated

Comment: I got an issue similar to this one. Wasted 3 hours trying to fix it by setting JAVA_HOME variable. And nothing. Finally, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182399/cant-compile-my-android-project and this helped to solve my problem. I suspect that even if it is not checked, old value is still used by VS somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually solved this by taking it to another device and running as administrator.
So if someone ran into a similar problem try running your cmd as administrator or check its permission. After obviously trying most of what was said on this post already and in the comments

**Update**

One issue I found on another device recently (2 years after the original issue) is I was running a shell version of CMD not the default CMD which was not gaining access to the Java_Home property. Be sure to check that as a possible cause as well.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to include any path in "User Variables for" section.

Just create JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME variables is "System variables" section.

After that something that you may have forgotten is to include those variables in "path" variable existing in "System variables" section as below:
 [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyQTT.png)

Comment: Thank you for trying Ali. But sadly I have already done this, just did not add it in my picture.Why is it not required to include them in the User Variables? do the the "System Variables" override the User Variables?

Comment: System variables can be acccessed by any profile, as well as local system credentials (such as those frequently associated with windows services).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I tried all the methods from uninstalling multiple versions, reinstalling latest version, tried inverted commas in paths etc.etc.
but the problem was really one invalid path in the existing path variable!!!
after removing it, this issue was solved

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Visual Studio. I updated the JAVA_HOME variable in tools => options => tools for apache cordova.